# How can I set up auto-reply for each email from the same sender?

Tags: gmail, automation

I am trying to set auto generated reply in Gmail using the vacation responder. But it will send the email after 4 days if same person sends another email.

I want to send reply for each email if same person sending me mail 10 times, he should get the 10 replies. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you pnuts, I have already solved this problem by using canned response in addition of using filter.

You can create a canned response(a template mail) and then on creating filter just attach the same with filter. You will get reply every time.